# Who is the Mother of Meliodas, Estarossa, and Zeldris?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

I don't think it ever comes up, but it's interesting to think about….

Who is the Mother of Meliodas, Estarossa, and Zeldris?

Comment: Demon King, being all powerful could have just conjured them with his dark and powerful magic. But that's in speculation too.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion, it's the supreme deity. Zeldris has a goddess symbol on his sword and Estarossa was a member of the archangels.